# Why are $W$ bosons massless above electroweak scale?

Tags: mass, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

Because of the Higgs mechanism, one must replace the Higgs field $\phi$ with $\phi_0 + \phi_1$ where $\phi_0$ is the vacuum expectation value. As far as I understand, the $\phi_0$ gives the mass term to bosons after developping the product $D_{\mu}\phi D^\mu \phi$. But I don't understand why these mass terms should disappear above the electroweak scale where it is said that the gauge bosons are massless.

Comment: Essence from the duplicate: They are *not* actually massless, but the corrections to the massless behaviour get ever smaller with rising energy scale.